# Get onClickItem to Link to a URL or a route in react-simple-tree-menu

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to get onClickItem to Link to a URL or a route in [react-simple-tree-menu](https://github.com/iannbing/react-simple-tree-menu).  Using their example:

```
<TreeMenu
  data={treeData}
  onClickItem={({ key, label, ...props }) => {
    this.navigate(props.url);  // this line throws the error
  }}
  initialActiveKey='first-level-node-1/second-level-node-1'
  debounceTime={125}>
</TreeMenu>
```

Gives an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
    at onClickItem
```

When an [item in the list is clicked](https://iannbing.github.io/react-simple-tree-menu/?path=/story/treemenu--default-usage), I'd like to link to a particular URL based on props.url or route to the id of the item clicked.

It shows the correct URL in the console for props.url and the correct id for props.id

```
<TreeMenu
  data={treeData}
  onClickItem={({ key, label, ...props }) => {
    // this.navigate(props.url);
    console.log(props.url, props.id);
  }}
  initialActiveKey='first-level-node-1/second-level-node-1'
  debounceTime={125}>
</TreeMenu>
```

Things I've tried (yeah, new to this):

```
<Link to={`/alignments/${props.id}`}></Link>
this.router.navigate.url(props.url);
this.navigation.navigate(props.url);
{this.props.navigation.navigate}
<Link to={props.url}></Link>
props.navigate(props.url);
```

Import statements at the top of the React function:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import TreeMenu from 'react-simple-tree-menu';
import '../node_modules/react-simple-tree-menu/dist/main.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still interested about the answer, but maybe someone else could find it useful. I tested your code and it works fine like this:

```
<TreeMenu
  data={treeData}
  onClickItem={({ key, label, ...props }) => {
    window.location.href = props.url;
  }}
  initialActiveKey='first-level-node-1/second-level-node-1'
  debounceTime={125}>
</TreeMenu>
```

or if you are using router, you can simply

```
props.history.push(props.url)
```

..or use link